# Applying AJAX to rating system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I've create this rating system that sends number 1-5 to a textfile, depening on which star the user clicked on.
At the same page we have a counter who counts number of votes, and the total amount of all votes.

The progress works fine, but I want to enchance it some.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="Star" id="Star">    
    <div id="rating-area" class="shadow">   

    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" data-value="1" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" data-value="2" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" data-value="3" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" data-value="4" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" data-value="5" />

    </div>


</form>



<script>


   jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery(this).data('value') ;
        console.log(val) ;
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ Star : val },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>



<?php

    $file = file("textfile.txt");
    $textfil = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");
    $textfill = str_split($textfil);


    echo "Number of votes in file: " . count($textfill) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($textfill as $vote) {
        $sum = $sum + intval($vote);
    }
    echo "Total: " . $sum;
?>
```

Im kind of new to this php, but is it possible to do an AJAX request so that we don't have to reload the page to get the updated count numbers?

What I need help with is to create an AJAX call so when the user onclick a star, the page will call for data from the textfile without realoading the whole page.

I think I posted all the necassary information, if not, please tell me and I will edit and try to give you the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would rather store this information in database than a text file but the concept is the same.

1.) Create a new PHP that reads the text file and gets the new 'Count' of votes or 'Score' whatever information you want to send back. For simple usage I would just echo this value.

2.) Add some more Javascript to go fetch this value after we have added the users count.

The example below gives a good overview of the concept (From W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). This example would take and then replace the return value into the webpage with the css 'ID' of 'txtHint'. This specfic example also gets the entire page and loads it into this ID, this will be fine if you are only echo'ing the vale to your browser.

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This should help you out, if you struggle getting it to work post back your code and can debug on from that.

Comment: Im totally new to this, so I might be abit slow.
But I have created a new page and copied in the php code that gets the value from the textfile.txt.
Im struggling with that code you posted. Im not sure what things to put inside of it. I guess that it is my textfile.txt that should be inside the () at the getelementbyid?
And at the xmttp.open("GET"...) What happens here?

Comment: Have you created PHP file that reads your txt file and provides an answer and echo's it to the page?

Comment: I created a new file called ajax.php where I pasted the php count code.
Im not sure how to echo it back to the main page. Is it "include("ajax.php");
echo $sum?

Comment: Just browse to http://localhost/ajax.php and see if it is displayed in the browser. the begin with.

Comment: Yes, all the numbers are there.

Comment: Ok good start, this is when not having SQL DB is going to make things difficult. You need to return a single number count of a given product or whatever you are rating. So implement `$ID = $_GET['ID'];` We can work with Get as its quicker than Get. Then add `?ID=1` to the end of your URL. With the ID matching a product or whatever your rating in your txt file and just return the single number. (This part will be a whole lot easier with MySQL and I would  advise learning MySQL before ajax/php to txt file) but do that.

Comment: In which file should I implement the $ID? ajax.php or the main page?
And at the end of my URL? Like, in the browser window?
Sorry, I must sound really stupid, but still learning:)

Comment: Ok, think doing this at the moment is out of your depth. I would go learn MySQL + PHP as this would make it alot easier. Start working through PHP on W3Schools and then once you know the PHP involve you can request it using javascript (AJAX).

Comment: No worries, good luck. Learn each part in turn. You will get through ;)